# Including Third-Party libraries via Composer in WordPress Plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, scope, composer-php, phpspreadsheet

Ok, so I've spent quite a bit of time on this and it's something that is clearly beyond me - I am creating a WordPress plugin, and I want to include the PHPSpreadsheet Library. I followed the instructions to install the Library using Composer (https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#installation), and I placed the sample code in a sub-file of my plugin:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('hello world.xlsx');
```

Now, I quickly discovered that I can't place the two lines with the 'use' declaration in this particular sub-file of my plugin - so I moved the first three lines to my main plugin file, and things were good - looks like I grabbed the 'autoload.php' just fine, and the 'use' statements weren't throwing any errors.

Back in my sub-file, I left the rest of the code, but all I get now are errors saying:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Spreadsheet' not found
```

There's clearly something about namespaces and scope here that I don't understand. Currently this is the code in my main plugin file:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

global $spreadsheet;
$GLOBALS['spreadsheet'] = new Spreadsheet();
```

I'm now able to access the 'Spreadsheet' variable in my sub-file, but this is obvisouly not ideal.

Any help anyone?? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understant why you want to move these lignes in another file ?

Comment: I obviously can't do all of my spreadsheet processing in the main file of my WordPress plugin - also, the spreadsheet processing needs to be done as an ajax call anyway upon a button click.

Comment: and why do you not use theses lignes "use ..." in the sub-file ?

Comment: Because I recieve this error when I try: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) - apparently the 'Use' declaration has to be used outside of any function, at a top-level scope - thus I placed them in my main WordPress Plugin File, before any other code.

Comment: the lines with "use" or "namespace" must be the first lines of the file, just after "<?php"

Comment: Are the include paths used properly? Starting from the first code example, is there a subfolder `vendor` containing the `autoload.php` and other folders for the dependencies?

Comment: @NicoHaase, yes I've for sure verified that the include path is correct and that autoload.php is indeed being loaded.